# How to inferSchema while pulling data from Salesforce object

Tags: python, amazon-s3, pyspark, salesforce, databricks

Whenever I am pulling data from Salesforce object into Databricks, all the columns in the Databricks is showing as type String. But I want the same data type that is being used in Salesforce. Hence I am trying to use the inferSchema=true option while loading. But that is not working.

Below is the query I am using for loading Salesforce object:

```
val sfDF = spark.
                read.
                format("com.springml.spark.salesforce").
                option("username", "your_salesforce_username").
                option("password", "your_salesforce_password_with_secutiry_token"). //<salesforce login password><security token>
                option("soql", soql).   
                option("inferSchema", "true").  
                option("version", "48.0").
                load()
```

I am getting the below error message:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 60 in stage 6231.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 60.3 in stage 6231.0 (TID 84032, 10.252.35.82, executor 99): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unexpected data type BooleanType
```

Is there any other way to inferSchema while pulling data from Salesforce object to Databricks?
Any suggestion would be very helpfull.